# Sylius - Setting Base Currency

Tags: sylius

I'm trying to change my Sylius base currency for EUR to USD. I've gone into the general settings section in the admin, and chosen USD. I've also edited my channel, and set the locale to EN.US, as well as the currency to USD in there.

I then went into the currencies section, and disabled all but USD. When I tried to disable EUR, I received a warning that this was the base currency and could not be disabled. So I went into the database (sylius_currency) and saw that both USD and EUR were set as enabled and as base. I disabled EUR, and also marked it as no longer being a base currency. Now I only have USD enabled and set as my base currency.

Then I cleared the cache, just in case.

Still, when I check the profiler I see EUR showing up as the base currency, and the every currency listed in both the backend and frontend are in EUR. How is this possible? A disabled currency no longer set as base is still being used instead of the enabled currency that is set to base. How can I get this change to come through correctly?

Comment: Check your parameters.yml file It's in there. I had the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, Brett! But my parameters.yml is also set for USD:

locale: en_US
currency: USD

Is there another option that maybe I'm missing?

Comment: Just checking you've opened in a new browser, might be a cookies thing?

Comment: Also try running a fresh composer install command and it should take you through the parameters set up again.

Comment: Very interesting. I was making sure the browser cache was clear, but ran a fresh composer install as you suggested. That didn't help, but I found that the old Euro pricing seems to be linked to the default sylius admin account (sylius@example.com) which I was using during development. As soon as I logged out, or into a new account I created, all the prices switched over correctly to USD on the front-end and back-end. Unfortunately I'm not sure which change was the one that did it, but the steps you've outlined here work. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things to check.

Run a composer install and it should ask you for your settings. This is sometimes hardcoded to a currency that doesn't exist for a channel. Update this.

Clear your cache with `cache:clear`

Carbide has mentioned he had to login as someone else before it would work.

Comment: Thanks, Brett! You've been extremely helpful :)